# DOM - timing of simultaneous events vs setTimeout

Tags: javascript, dom, language-lawyer, dom-events, event-loop

Suppose I have an element containing several children and want to run some code whenever the mouse enters or leaves the container.  If I naively write:

```
var onHover = function (el, f) {
    el.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
        f(true);
    });
    el.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
        f(false);
    });
};
```

Then I get the desired behavior in some cases - depending on the nature of the callback `f`.  However, when the mouse moves from child to child *within* the container, `f(false)` runs immediately followed by `f(true)`.  I don't want this to happen - I only want `f` to be run when the mouse enters or leaves the container as a whole, not called machine-gun style as the user drags their mouse over the elements that are inside the container.

Here's the solution that I came up with:

```
var onHover = function (el, f) {
    var previousMouseover = false;
    var receivedMouseover = false;
    var pushing = false;
    var pushEv = function () {
        if (pushing) { return; }
        pushing = true;
        setTimeout(function () {
            pushing = false;
            if (previousMouseover !== receivedMouseover) {
                f(receivedMouseover);
                previousMouseover = receivedMouseover;
            }
        });
    };
    el.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
        receivedMouseover = true;
        pushEv();
    });
    el.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
        receivedMouseover = false;
        pushEv();
    });
};
```

This solution, like the first solution, assumes and works by the virtue that the `mouseout` event is sent before the `mouseover` event is.  I would also like to know whether *that* is formally specified by any W3C documentation, but that is not the topic of this question, and even if it were not the case, it would be easy to write a functioning algorithm in spite of that by setting two separate variables, say `receivedMouseover` and `receivedMouseout` inside of the `mouseover` and `mouseout` callbacks, both of which are then inspected inside of the `setTimeout` callback.

The question is:  Is it required that both the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events be processed *before* any `setTimeout` callbacks signed up by either event are run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

Comment: TIL: Not all DOM events bubble.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have attached the event listener to the parent element you may compare the event origin (`event.target`) with the parent element (`this` or `event.currentTarget`) before you take an action. You may do as follows;

```
var onHover = function (el, f) {
    el.addEventListener('mouseover', function (evt) {
        this === evt.target && f(true);
    });
    el.addEventListener('mouseout', function (evt) {
        this === evt.target && f(false);
    });
};
```

Most of the elements bubble so at some point this might be the right way to do this job.

**Edit:** As mentioned in the comments the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events can be problematic under some circumstances such as when the parent element has no padding or margins defined and children cover all the parent. Even if they don't the speed of the mouse could be fast enough to make the JS engine fail to sample the mouse over the parent element. [This fact is beautifuly explained in this article](https://javascript.info/mousemove-mouseover-mouseout-mouseenter-mouseleave#events-mouseenter-and-mouseleave).

So, as mentioned in the accepted answer, i suppose the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events are there to solve this problem. Accordingly the right code should be like;

```
var onHover = function (el, f) {
    el.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => f(true));
    el.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => f(false));
};
```

**Edit 2:** Well... Actually there is a safe way of using `mouseover` and `mouseout` in this particular condition. It's about using CSS `pointer-events` property on the children which disables them from event emitting for mouse activity.

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container');

container.addEventListener('mouseover', function (ev) {
  console.log(container === ev.target);
});

container.addEventListener('mouseout', function (ev) {
  console.log(container === ev.target);
});
```

```css
#container * {
  pointer-events: none
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <span>text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, that will not work reliably.  If the container is entirely filled with child elements, `this === evt.target` will never be true.  See [this codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MGjMgz)

Comment: @jcarpenter2 You seem to be right when the parent's `<div>` child perfectly overlap. It's already 4AM here. I will look into this tomorrow, also for my own curiosity. At the meantime a 1px padding on `container ` solves it though. :)

Comment: In my browser, the 1px padding only works if you don't move the mouse too quickly.  Also it is dangerously close to, or crossing the line of, modifying the page layout in order to program against it correctly - some ugly CSS hacks would be needed to get the 1px padding technique to work without having the collateral effect of actually adding a visual 1px padding.  I appreciate your creativity, though.

Comment: @jcarpenter2 Yes right.. It's seems the only way is the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events as mentioned in the accepted answer. Editted my post accordingly and attached a link explaining.

Comment: @jcarpenter2 I guess under this topic it's also worth mentioning that the CSS [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) property can help us to use `mouseover` and `mouseout` with desired functionality too. Extended answer to show an example.